# Where is openerp 7.0-20140117-002509-1 installed folder after installation of openerp7.0?

Tags: openerp-7

I have installed openerp 7.0 in Ubuntu 12.04, after installed the openerp 7.0 i am seeking that openerp 7.0/server/addons folder to install  new module but i can't find the correct path/location

Could any one help me to solve this problem please....

Answer (score 1):

You can refer path of addons with config file.
Here is snippet from OpenERP 7 server, so you need to add paths after **addons_path** keyword. As you can see there are 2 folders. 1st one for **my custom addons**, other one for **openerp virgin addons**. You can pass many other argument inside conf file, if you wish I can show whole config file content.
You can use conf file as shown on first row with ubuntu terminal.

> python openerp-server -c erp_mycorp.conf
>   addons_path = ./mycustom,./openerp/addons

# specify the database user
db_user = erpdummyser

# specify the database password
db_password = dummypass

# specify the pg executable path
pg_path = None

# specify the database host
db_host = False

# specify the database port
db_port = False

Answer (score 0):

OpenERP 7 has 3 folders of reference, for example, if you have downloaded in your catella OpenERP 7.0, you will have:

7.0/server
7.0/addons
7.0/web

now if you'd like to add your modules, you can do it in 2 ways:

1) add your module in 7.0/addons

2) create a folder in 7.0/mymodule, now how do you start OpenERP eg:

```
 7.0/server/./openerp-server -u user -r PASSWORD --addons-path = 7.0/addons, 7.0/myaddons
```

now in OpenERP, you can update the module list and you will find your module to be